# how to place the document url in text input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, url

I'm not quite sure how I should get the top URL and then place it in a text input? Here's what I've come up with, but no luck. Anyone have any ideas? Also, how could I make this text input non editable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var topURL = document.URL; 
    function SelectAll(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
        document.getElementById(id).select();  
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="txtfld" onClick="SelectAll('txtfld');" style="width:200px" value ="topURL" />
```

I also tried `value ="document.URL"` in the value parameter and `value ="document.write(document.URL)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var topURL = document.URL; 
    function SelectAll(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
        document.getElementById(id).select();

    }
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="txtfld" onClick="SelectAll('txtfld');" style="width:200px" value ="topURL" />
<script language="javascript">
 document.getElementById('txtfld').value = topURL;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in a script:

```
document.getElementById('txtfld').value = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Agreed.  Drop the inline javascript.  I'm sure you were waiting all day for my approval.

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href` would get it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty clear.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var topURL = document.URL; 
    function SelectAll(id)
    {
        var foo=document.getElementById(id) 
        foo.value=topURL

    }
    </script>

    <input type="text" id="txtfld" onClick="SelectAll('txtfld');"
style="width:200px" value ="topURL" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest I have found is

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
     document.write('<input type="text" name="pgUrl" value="' + document.URL + '">');
</script>
```

Although would really like to know how to get rid of the http://  :)